# Converting C "FOR" loop to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, for-loop

I'm trying to convert a FOR loop from C to Delphi, but I'm with some doubts:

**I know this code in C:**

```
       for (i = 0; i < mb->size; i++)
       {
           //...
       }
```

**is like this in Delphi:**

```
       for i := 0 to mb.size do 
       begin
           //...
       end;
```

---

But how is this C code:

```
       for (i = 0; i < mb->size; i+= mb->data_size)
       {
        //...
       }
```

might look in Delphi?

```
       ?
```

Comment: 1) use a "while" loop instead of "for"  2) Your C and Delphi examples are *NOT* the same.  The delphi should read "for i := 0 to mb.size - 1 do"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use a for in delphi to do this because the variable used to iterate cannot be modified.

So this code

```
for (i = 0; i < mb->size; i+= mb->data_size)
```

can be written using a while

```
  i:=0;
  while (i<mb.size) do
  begin
   // do something
   Inc(i, mb.data_size);
  end;
```