# Convert C++ FOR loop to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting C “FOR” loop to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986346/converting-c-for-loop-to-delphi)

I'm trying to convert a C++ FOR loop to Delphi, but I have no idea how to do it...

this is the C++ function:

```
bool bCompare(const BYTE* pData, const BYTE* bMask, const char* szMask)
{
    for(;*szMask;++szMask,++pData,++bMask)
        if(*szMask=='x' && *pData!=*bMask)   return 0;
    return (*szMask) == NULL;
}
```

I just got convert the function declaration:

```
function bCOmpare( pData: PBYTE; bMask: PBYTE; szMask: PCHAR):boolean;
begin
//...
end;
```

How is the conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function bCOmpare(pData: PByte; bMask: PByte; szMask: PAnsiChar): Boolean;
begin
  while szMask^<>#0 do
  begin
    if ((szMask^='x') and (pData^<>bMask^)) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
    inc(szMask);
    inc(pData);
    inc(bMask);
  end;
  Result := True;//the test in the C code is pointless
end;
```

Comment: Just avoid using ``PAnsiChar``. Use its generic type ``PChar``.

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez No, that's poor advice. On Delphi 2009 and later `Char` is 2 bytes wide. In C and C++ on Windows, `char` is always 1 byte wide. The change from `PChar` in the question to `PAnsiChar` in my answer was made very intentionally for that reason.